# Removing white space from every single input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am working on an application, where it's important to have leading and trailing white spaces removed, before saving to the DB.

I was planning on writing a helper method, to do:

```
if !self.attribute_name.nil?
  self.attribute_name = self.attribute_name.strip
end
```

and calling it for every single attribute, in the various models, as a before_save action.

Can you think of simpler way to do this?

Comment: There are a lot of gems that handle this for you that I use.  One is:  https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes

Then you just include it in each model file instead of every controller for create/update actions.

Comment: @bkunzi01: if you turn this into an answer, I will give you credit for it. The gem also has the added benefit of allowing me to remove extra white spaces within strings, as well as extra lines (as options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of gems that handle this for you that I use. One is: github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes

Then you just include it in each model file instead of every controller for create/update actions

Comment: I understand this is not supported in Rails > 3.2, but my app is Rails 3.2

Comment: It works for 4.2 as well however I haven't tested against Rails 5.0.  I've used the following for Rails 5 (Less options however) : https://github.com/thomasfedb/attr_cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Replacements can be done with the gsub methods. These are substitution methods. gsub applies the substitution globally.

You can use gsub also

```
if !self.attribute_name.nil?
  self.attribute_name = self.attribute_name.gsub(" ", "")
end
```

Comment: Please don't use html/js/css snippet for something that is not a runnable bundle of html/js/css. Especially ruby code.

Comment: That also does not address my question, as in it does not remove the requirement to call this method for every single attribute.